# Can multiple queries be applied to a model in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-7

I'm currently trying to get data from the DB with a Laravel controller through a model `Maintain`. Is there a way to query the DB based on the request data made by an axios post from the front end, this includes both variables `sub` and `zone`, I have the ability to get the data from using `sub` OR `zone` but not both, is there a way to construct a multi where query if `$request` contains the necessary variables and a standard request if they are `null` or `""`?

```
  public function all(Request $request){
    $query = [];
    if($request->sub != ""){
      array_push($query, ['subsystem', '=', $request->sub]);
    }
    if($request->zone != ""){
      array_push($query, ['zone', '=', $request->zone]);
    }

    if(count($query) > 0){
      return Maintain::all()->where($query);
    }
    else{
      return Maintain::all();
    }
  }
```

Currently This returns with an error `ErrorException: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer in file` but I've been using the Laravel reference and it doesn't seem to be working. I used Postman to get the readout of `$query` and it contains the following:

```
[
 ['sub', '=', 'Subsystem 1'],
 ['zone', '=', 'Zone 1']
]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
public function all(Request $request){

   $result = Maintain::when($request->zone, function ($q) use($request){
      $q->where('zone', $request->zone);
   })
   ->when($request->sub, function ($qw) use($request){
      $qw->where('subsystem', $request->sub);
   })
   ->get();

   return($result);
}
```

`when()` method look like if-else

Edited: Let we know if you get an error: Happy coding

Comment: Can I also use this for sub as well? So would it effectively function as an AND if I used it afterwards?

Comment: Yes you can. ```when()``` method is really effective to handle ```$request->zone``` if not null, happy coding

Comment: I changed it to the following 
```public function all(Request $request){
    $data = Maintain::all();

    $data = Maintain::when($request->zone, function ($query){
      $query->where('zone', $request->zone);
    })->get();

    $data = Maintain::when($request->sub, function ($query){
      $query->where('zone', $request->sub);
    })->get();

    return $data;
  }
```
But it comes up saying that it can't find the `$request` variable

Comment: Thank you, but I updated it to what you suggested and it seems that it comes back with the error `ErrorException: Undefined variable: request`
If I put `$request` into the function inside the `when` I get error: `ErrorException: Trying to get property 'zone' of non-object`

Comment: Yes, that has worked, thank you very much, I'm sorry about the extra questions, I didn't know you could pass variables in to the function with `use`

Comment: Ok no problem, happy coding